# How compilers identify the length of byte shift operators

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Consider the following line:

`int mask = 1 << shift_amount;`

we know that `mask` is 4 bytes because it was explicitly declared `int`, but this `1` that to be shifted has unknown length. If the compiler chose type as `char` it would be 8 bits, or it could be `unsigned short` with size 16 bits, so shifting result will really depend on the size of the compiler's decision about how to treat that `1`. How does the compiler decide here? And is it safe to leave the code this way or should it instead be:

`int flag = 1`;

`int mask = flag << shift_amount;`

Comment: `1` is a literal of type `int`; it's not a matter of choice, the C++ standard says so.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 1+, that's an answer I will accept for the question.

Comment: _"we know that mask is 4 bytes because it was explicitly declared int"_ `int` isn't necessarily 4 bytes

Comment: _"this 1 that to be shifted has unknown length"_ no it doesn't

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I know it can be 2 bytes on x86 machines, i think it's wiser to use int32_t which will enforce size. The second comment about the mysterious size of 1 is equally mysterious :) do you mean it will be as big as `int` is treated?

Comment: @doc_id It _is_ an `int`! That's an `int` literal. There's nothing "mysterious" about it. In fact the only thing "mysterious" is why your C++ book didn't mention it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1` is an `int` (typically 4 bytes).  If you wanted it to be a type other than `int` you'd use a suffix, like `1L` for `long`.  For more details see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal.

You can also use a cast like `(long)1` or if you want a known fixed length, `(int32_t)1`.

As Eric Postpischil points out in a comment, values smaller than `int` like `(short)1` are not useful because the left-hand argument to `<<` is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: @Ruslan I've never seen that used in C++; not even once. I'm not saying you _can't_, but your readers would be confused. A nice cast to `uint32_t` will, in practice, be free, and is much clearer to read and to debug.

Comment: @Ruslan Also be aware that those macros _don't_ give you fixed-width types; `UINT32_C(x)` resolves to something like `uint_least32_t(x)`, which can be more than 32 bits wide.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  I've never even seen it in any real C code either. AFAIK, casts always do the job except in preprocessor conditionals (`#if`) where a literal/suffix might be required. (the _C macros effectively add an integer suffix such (`u`, `ul`, `ull`, `l`, `ll`) if it's needed; they don't cast).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yeah, that's why I've removed my comment.

Comment: `(short)1` will not “work” to make the shift act on less than an `int`; the left operand of `<<` is always promoted to at least `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Great point, amended that example to `(long)` instead of `(short)`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The 2018 C standard says in 6.4.4 3:

> Each constant has a type, determined by its form and value, as detailed later.

This means we can always tell what the type of a constant is just from the text of the constant itself, without regard to the expression it appears in. (Here, “constant” actually means a literal: A thing whose value is given by its text. For example `34` and `'A'` literally represent the number 34 and the character A, in contrast to an identifier `foo` that refers to some object.)

(This answer addresses C specifically. The rules described below are different in C++.)

The subclauses of 6.4.4 detail the various kinds of constants (integers, floating-point, enumerations, and characters). An integer constant without a suffix that can be represented in an `int` is an `int`, so `1` is an `int`.

If an integer constant has a suffix or does not fit in an `int`, then its type is affected by its suffix, its value, and whether it is decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, according to a table in 6.4.4.1 5.

Floating-point constants are `double` if they have no suffix, `float` with `f` or `F`, and `long double` with `l` or `L`.

Enumeration constants (declared with `enum`) have type `int`. (And these are not directly literals as I describe above, because they are names for values, but the name does indicate the value by way of the `enum` declaration.)

Character constants without a prefix have type `int`. Constants with prefixes `L`, `u`, or `U` have type `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t`, respectively.

Comment: `'c'` is a literal of type `int` not type `char`? Really?

Comment: @NathanPierson: It is in C++ (C++ draft n4659 5.13.3 2). Not in C.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. Didn't notice the asker had tagged it with both languages and your answer was regarding C.